# Maven jasperreports-maven-plugin define compile charset

Tags: maven-2, jasper-reports

When using the jasperreports-maven-plugin/1.0-beta-2 to compile a jrxml file to jasper, the resulting report doesn't display unicode characters properly, it displays ???? instead.

It is obvious this is a font problem. So I opened iReport 4.0.1, and compiled the jrxml file from there without changing any specific settings, the resulting jasper file could display the unicode characters just fine. So I am assuming there are some compile time properties which I am not setting properly.

I thought of using the  tag of the jasperreports-maven-plugin plugin, to define the resulting encoding properties to the used when compiling the jasper file. But I couldnt find what properties to set there.

I guessed some properties from

[The JasperReport Configuration Reference](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/config.reference.html)

specifically

```
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding
net.sf.jasperreports.export.character.encoding
```

but to no avail.

So I would like to know either if iReport uses some special compilation options regarding fonts,encoding or charset properties that can be set in the asperreports-maven-plugin mojo.

Alernatively, if this is not possible from this mojo.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The Maven plugin is most likely not using JasperReports 4.0.1 to compile the report.  By default it uses the JasperReports defined as a dependency: jasperreports:jasperreports:1.2.0.

Because JasperReports 4.0.1 has a different group, artifact and version this dependency can't be overridden.  Exclusions only work for dependencies of dependencies, so that isn't an option either.  You will need a different version of the mojo to compile templates using 4.0.1.

Lucky for you a patch has already been applied to the trunk of the mojo so all you have to do is check out the code and deploy a version to your repository.

http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/trunk/mojo/jasperreports-maven-plugin/

After deploying the plugin you will need to override the dependency to 4.0.1.  You do this by defining dependencies at the plugin level.

`<plugin>

    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>

    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>

            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>

            <version>4.0.1</version>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</plugin>`

Comment: Here is how to "check out the code and deploy a version to your repository":

   svn co -r14769 "svn.codehaus.org/mojo/trunk/mojo/jasperreports-maven-plugin" jrmp;
   cd jrmp;
   mvn install;

Sorry for the formating. It wouldn't let me put returns in.