# Is there a way to include jrxml source for a Jasper subreport?

Tags: jasper-reports

We are working on a project with jasper reports where we lazily compile Jasper reports in memory. Is there a way to also lazily compile a subreport in memory and use it with the parent report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. The subreportExpression does not have to be of type string. It can actually be a JasperReport object. So I will just compile the subreport in memory and pass it to the report as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would use:

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[JasperCompileManager.compileReport($P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/myFile.jrxml")]]></subreportExpression>
```

Answer (score 1):

[A little late but still relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369784/maven-jasperreports-maven-plugin-define-compile-charset). The previous link shows how to get your jrxml to compile automatically with maven.